# comparing character array and character pointer using strcmp

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "ab";
    char *s1 = "ab";

    if(strcmp(s, s1))
        printf("%d", 24);
    else
        printf("%d", 23);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Why it is giving 23 answer?

Comment: Here, have a look at [what `strcmp` does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: Because the strings are equal, strcmp returns 0. man strcmp!

Comment: Removed C++ tag and removed C language reference from title.

Comment: Yaa..Got that .silly question to ask .:P.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `strcmp` returns `0` if strings are equal. `0` is treated as `false` in C.

```
strcmp(string1, string2)
```

#### Return Value

```
if Return value < 0 then it indicates string1 is less than string2

if Return value > 0 then it indicates string2 is less than string1

if Return value = 0 then it indicates string1 is equal to string2
```

Answer (score 4):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the given strings are equal, as in this case. `0` is converted to `false`, so the `else` block is executed, printing `23`.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` on success returns `0`. Hence `if` will fail.

Change `if` statement as,

```
if(strcmp(s , s1) == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings compare equal.